# Passing a file through a function in c

Tags: c, function, file, pointers

Now whenever i run this it opens up a "Make a file" tab and gives me an error saying [something wrong with line 25 from that tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eg6D.png). Not sure if its the way im passing it through.

Another problem is if i name the file " Anything" it will appear is " A@@ "

Thank you
(closed the file  just to test it )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void generateFile(char,FILE);
void inputFile(int,FILE);
void printFile();


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char fname;
    int max_num;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Enter file name \n");
    scanf("%c", &fname);

    printf("Enter max_num \n");
    scanf("%d",&max_num);

    FILE *fp;

    generateFile(fname,*fp);
    inputFile(max_num,*fp);




    return 0;
}

void generateFile(char fname,FILE *fp){


    fp = fopen( &fname, "w");

    fprintf(fp,"Testing");



    return;
}

void inputFile(int max_num, FILE *fp){

    int i,array[25];

    for(i=0;i<max_num;i++){
        array[i] = rand() % 100 + 50;
        fprintf(fp,"%d\n",array[i]);

        fclose(fp);



    }

}
```

Comment: `fname` should be a `char *` not a `char`

Comment: Take a look at your function prototypes, and compare them with the definitions (implementations) of the functions. The arguments doesn't match. And you should *never* pass a `FILE` by value.

Comment: Also, search for and read about *emulating pass by reference in c*. The `generateFile` function will not do what you hope it will do. I suggest *returning* the `FILE*` instead.

Comment: alright thanks! ill work on it and get back to you! @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `fp` incorrectly. You can either pass-by-reference:

```
void generateFile(char *fname, FILE **fp)
    *fp = fopen(fname, "w");
    // Check for error....
    fprintf(*fp, "Testing");
    return;
}
```

Usage: `generateFile(fname, &fp);`

Or, I prefer, have the function return a pointer:

```
FILE * void generateFile(char *fname) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "w");
    // Check for error....
    fprintf(fp, "Testing");
    return fp;
}
```

Usage: `FILE *fp = generateFile(fname);`

And the name should be pass as a `char *`, or `const char *`.

Also, in the next call, just pass the pointer:

```
inputFile(max_num, fp);
```

And, you should also check that the file was successfully opened.

And, remove `fclose(fp);` from the `for` loop else only the 1st write will succeed.